# CSS & HTML: Img verticaly centered to a block of text

Tags: html, image

I am searching for Image verticaly centered to a block of text like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2w4e7ut/8

It is possibly without using a table? I have not found a solution on the WEB.

Here is a part of solution from stackoverflow which I have tried to adjust:

http://goo.gl/rwu106

but without a success.

Comment: Add your code.. what you have done so far..

Answer (score 0):

I added another option in my answer as per the fiddle you updated in your question.

Now in the option I've used the same fiddle you added in your question.

**Option 1**

To make the "float:left" vertically align middle, you need to add the below hack

.parentDIV {
        position:relative;
}

.child{
        float: left;
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto 0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
}

here is the updated CSS for the same:

```
#content {
    margin-left: 210px;
    border:1px solid red;
    /* just to show the different boxes */
}
#theDiv {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ccc;
    /* just to show the vertical align boxes */
}
#theDiv img {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid black;
    /* just to show the different boxes */
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%
}
```

Here is the **updated fiddle** for the same

**http://jsfiddle.net/ewxn3/241/**

==========================================================

**Option 2**
Try using "`display:table` and `display: table-cell;`" for DIVs to create a vertically align middle image but using DIV.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">Some content goes here. Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here. Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here. Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.Some content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    width: 348px;
    display: table;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    /* just to see it vertically aligned */
}
#content {
    width: 364px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#image {
    width: 400px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#image img {
    width:200px;
}
```

**Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9o5scd6c/**

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: if my answer helped you.. can you please upvate and select my answer for your question!!! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I agree!! but I added the first option since you have mentioned similar code in your  question which did't work for you..